# How to combine tuples with the same key value when combine lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to combine multiple lists into one list, the values with the same tuple key  must been add together.

For example:

```
A = [ (1,2),(5,2) ]
B = [ (1,2),(5,5),(11,2) ]
```

Expected result:

```
result = [ (1,4),(5,7),(11,2) ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite simply once you realise the idea of keeping track of the first element is done well with a `dict`

```
c = dict(A)
for key, value in B:
    c[key] = c.get(key, 0) + value

result = list(c.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important, using `collections.Counter` is another option:

```
In [21]: from collections import Counter

In [22]: A = [ (1,2),(5,2) ]

In [23]: B = [ (1,2),(5,5),(11,2) ]

In [24]: (Counter(dict(A)) + Counter(dict(B))).items() # list(...) for Python 3
Out[24]: [(1, 4), (11, 2), (5, 7)]
```